# How to remove Flashing Effect on Controls Inside the Picturebox (.gif)

Tags: c#

I have this picturebox(.gif animation) on my windows form. And I tried to add label into it. But when I run the program. The label background inside the picture box had something like glitching or flashing effect. Is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: try to move the focus away from the control

Comment: You can try to draw the Text in the Picturebox's Paint event.

Answer (score 0):

The Control class has a [DoubleBuffered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered(v=vs.110).aspx) property and it is designed to reduce flicker. It might help.

Comment: PictureBox is Double-Buffered by default.